# Find and highlight a specific word in a range of cells

Tags: excel, vba

I want to find a specific word in a range of cells then highlight it in red. To do so I created this code but it just worked on one line and highlighted all the cell text:

```
Sub Find_highlight()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim match As Range
    Dim findMe As String

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MYSHEET")
    findMe = "Background"

    Set match = ws.Range("G3:G1362").Find(findMe)
    match.Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
End Sub
```

Comment: @pnuts: My apologies. Didn't know that link existed. I have also voted it as a dup. :)

Answer (score 7):

Let's say your excel file looks like htis

[image]

To color specific word, you have to use the cell's `.Characters` property. You need to find where does the word start from and then color it.

Try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim sPos As Long, sLen As Long
    Dim aCell As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim findMe As String

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MYSHEET")

    Set rng = ws.Range("G3:G1362")

    findMe = "Background"

    With rng
        Set aCell = .Find(What:=findMe, LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            sPos = InStr(1, aCell.Value, findMe)
            sLen = Len(findMe)

            aCell.Characters(Start:=sPos, Length:=sLen).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: did you try with more than 1 line?

Comment: No I didn't. I am sure you can take care of that since I already showed you the method?

Comment: I don't know, the range is specified but it only performs the action with only one line!!!

Comment: You need to find all the starting positions of the search word and then use the `.Characters` methos to color all of them.

Comment: Honestly, I can't see the solution since I'm a beginner with vba.
Do you mean I should use a `for`?

Comment: see the link given by @pnuts below your question.

Answer (score 1):

i made some change to be more general and accurate

```
Option Explicit
Sub HIGHLIGHTER()
Dim sPos As Long, sLen As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim findMe As String
Dim i As Integer

Set rng = Application.InputBox(Prompt:= _
    "Please Select a range", _
    Title:="HIGHLIGHTER", Type:=8)
findMe = Application.InputBox(Prompt:= _
    "FIND WHAT?(YOU CAN USE PATTERN USED IN LIKE OPERATOR ", _
    Title:="HIGHLIGHTER", Type:=2)
  For Each rng In rng
    With rng
     If rng.Value Like "*" & findMe & "*" Then
        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
                   For i = 1 To Len(rng.Value)
                   sPos = InStr(i, rng.Value, findMe)
                   sLen = Len(findMe)
                   If (sPos <> 0) Then
                    rng.Characters(Start:=sPos, Length:=sLen).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                    i = sPos + Len(findMe) - 1
                   End If
                   Next i
       End If
     End If
    End With
   Next rng
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

added an option to loop

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()
    Dim sPos As Long, sLen As Long
    Dim aCell As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim findMe As String

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    Set rng = ws.Range("A3:A322")

    findMe = "find"

   For Each rng In Selection
    With rng
        Set aCell = .Find(What:=findMe, LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            sPos = InStr(1, aCell.Value, findMe)
            sLen = Len(findMe)

            aCell.Characters(Start:=sPos, Length:=sLen).Font.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
        End If
    End With
    Next rng
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I too made some changes to allow for searching multiple words at the same time. I also took away the prompts and hard coded the search words. The only issue left is to make the search non-case sensitive...

```
Sub HIGHLIGHTER()
Dim sPos As Long, sLen As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim findMe As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim t As Integer
Dim SearchArray

SearchArray = Array("WORD1", "WORD2")

For t = 0 To UBound(SearchArray)

    Set rng = Range("N2:N10000")
    findMe = SearchArray(t)

    For Each rng In rng
        With rng
            If rng.Value Like "*" & findMe & "*" Then
                If Not rng Is Nothing Then
                    For i = 1 To Len(rng.Value)
                        sPos = InStr(i, rng.Value, findMe)
                        sLen = Len(findMe)

                        If (sPos <> 0) Then
                            rng.Characters(Start:=sPos, Length:=sLen).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                            rng.Characters(Start:=sPos, Length:=sLen).Font.Bold = True
                            i = sPos + Len(findMe) - 1
                        End If
                    Next i
                End If
            End If
        End With
    Next rng

Next t
End Sub
```

Comment: You could change `If rng.Value Like "*" & findMe & "*" Then` to `If LCase(rng.Value) Like "*" & LCase(findMe) & "*" Then`.  This compares lower case to lower case.  Do the same with `sPos = InStr(i, rng.Value, findMe)` and change it to `sPos = InStr(i, LCase(rng.Value), LCase(findMe))`.