# Find and Highlight Cells Containing Specific Text

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I'm very new to VBA and I'm attempting to create a Sub that can find and highlight any cells in a worksheet that contain a particular text.

I've modeled my code after Pradeepta Pradhan's code in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215498/find-and-highlight-a-specific-word-in-a-range-of-cells).

The sub I wrote works, but it is extremely slow. Any hints on how to speed this up or clean up my code?

```
Sub Find_Highlight_Comments3()
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Match As Range
    Dim Comment As String

    Set WS = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Report Sheet 1")
    Set Rng = WS.UsedRange
    Comment = ("insoluble residue")
    Comment = ("non-gaussian")
    Comment = ("empty source well")
    Comment = ("source vial not received")
    Comment = ("foreign object")
    Comment = ("lacks nitrogen")
    Comment = ("lacks molecular")
    Comment = ("could not be assayed")
    Comment = ("not pass through Millipore filter")
    For Each Rng In Rng
    With Rng
        Set Match = WS.Cells.Find(What:=Comment, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
            If Not Match Is Nothing Then
                Match.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
            End If
    End With
    Next Rng
End Sub
```

Comment: As far as I can tell the only cells highlighted would be the `"not pass through Millipore filter"` and why not use Conditional Formatting?

Comment: If you want to go this route, then look into `FindNext` instead of looping through all your worksheet cells. Also see the comment above. If there are ways to avoid VBA you might consider that. Beware that conditional formatting is volatile and therefor has it's own cons.

Comment: Also, `For Each Rng In Rng` it is a bad idea to use the same object variable name for both the range you are looping through and the looping variable.

Comment: @ScottCraner You're right, the sub doesn't identify all the comments I listed as comments. Why does it only call "not pass through Millipore filter," and how would I get it to refer to the other comments?

Comment: @jkpieterse Should I change it to `For Each Rng In WS.Cells`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Little modification to your code. As you mentioned about Pradeepta Pradhan's post, I have put additional lines to highlight the comment text with red font. You can refer to [Siddharth's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20215657/9808063) below the same post.

I have put all those comments in comments array. If you want to add two more comments then first change the redim statement to 10. Note that array starts from index 0. Also, just find is not enough if you want to find all subsequent occurances of the same comment. So, added findnext as well.

```
Sub Find_Highlight_Comments3()
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim Match As Range
Dim Comment() As String

Set WS = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Report Sheet 1")

ReDim Comment(8)
    Comment(0) = "insoluble residue"
    Comment(1) = "non-gaussian"
    Comment(2) = "empty source well"
    Comment(3) = "source vial not received"
    Comment(4) = "foreign object"
    Comment(5) = "lacks nitrogen"
    Comment(6) = "lacks molecular"
    Comment(7) = "could not be assayed"
    Comment(8) = "not pass through Millipore filter"

For i = LBound(Comment) To UBound(Comment)
Set Match = WS.Cells.Find(What:=Comment(i), LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not Match Is Nothing Then
    FirstAddress = Match.Address
        Do
        sPos = InStr(1, Match.Value, Comment(i))
        sLen = Len(Comment(i))
        Match.Characters(Start:=sPos, Length:=sLen).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        Match.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        Set Match = WS.Cells.FindNext(Match)
        Loop While Not Match Is Nothing And Match.Address <> FirstAddress
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much!